# force click event to occur without click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written one function in angular js which is called on click on any button using `ng-click` . I have to call event on page load ? how can i call event from js directely without `click`.

**`$scope.$emit`  i tried but it is not working !!**

```
   $scope.loaddcurrent = function(pagename) {
            console.log('called'+pagename);
            $scope.templateurl = pagename;

            if (pagename == "gallery.html") {
                //Initially loading image data as gallery is initially set to image

                console.log('gallery .html is --------->');
                $scope.images = [];
                $scope.imageCategories = [];
                $scope.currentImage = {};
                $scope.images = Gallery.query({
                    media : "image"
                });

                //Not used below part currently
                $scope.currentImage = _.first($scope.images);
                $scope.imageCategories = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.images, 'category'));

            }


        };
```

Comment: I don't see any clicks in that code. Why are you not calling `loaddcurrent` directly?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv i tried $scope.loaddcurrent(); but it gives error $scope.loadcurrent is not a function..

Comment: `loadcurrent` or `load*d*current`?

Comment: @sergiuParaschiv loadcurrent...

Comment: Then please post your complete code here.

Answer (score 0):

please, put an id on a div (or component) with ng-control:

```
<div id="myControl" ng-control="MyControl">
```

and now, you can call after dom load

```
$(function() {
    angular.element(document.getElementById('myControl')).scope().loaddcurrent();
});
```

of course, if you not use jquery, call on window.load... but I prefer jquery :-)

Comment: Why would you access the scope like that? It would be much more angular-y to write a directive to do that and attach it wherever you need it.